# Crystal Reports ExportToDisk function

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, reportdocument

I have a C# application that generates a hundreds of different reports at a time using Crystal Reports templates and saves them to a network share using the ReportDocumnet.ExportToDisk function. While this works great I've noticed that it **sometimes** leaves a copy of the completed report in the root of the drive that the program is residing on. It does not do this all the time which is confusing.

The current version of the program is a console app and is not multi threaded.

Any ideas why this happens?

```
try{CR.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFrmat, Filepath + FileName);}
```